# LINQ vs foreach vs for performance test results

Tags: c#, performance, linq, for-loop, foreach

Could somebody explain these results?
I know there are duplicate questions, but I have yet to find a single question that came to the same conclusion as my results :o

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SpeedTest
{
    class Person
    {    
        public Person(string name)
        {
            this.Name = name;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var people = new List<Person>();
            AddTwins("FRANCISCO", people);
            var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

            string name = "OCSICNARF";

            long linqTime = 0L;
            long foreachTime = 0L;
            long forTime = 0L;

            stopwatch.Start();
            Person person0;
            var result = from person in people
                         where person.Name == name
                         select person;
            person0 = result.First();
            linqTime = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            stopwatch.Restart();
            Person person1;
            foreach (Person p in people)
            {
                if (p.Name == name)
                {
                    person1 = p;
                    break;
                }
            }
            foreachTime = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            stopwatch.Restart();
            Person person2;
            for (int i = 0; i < people.Count; i++)
            {
                if (people[i].Name == name)
                {
                    person2 = people[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
            forTime = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            stopwatch.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("LINQ took {0}ms", linqTime));
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("FOREACH took {0}ms", foreachTime));
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("FOR took {0}ms", forTime));
        }

        static void AddTwins(string name, List<Person> people)
        {
            AddTwins(people, name, "");
        }

        private static void AddTwins(List<Person> people, string choices, string chosen)
        {
            if (choices.Length == 0)
            {
                people.Add(new Person(chosen));
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < choices.Length; i++)
                {
                    // choose
                    char c = choices[i];
                    string choose1 = choices.Substring(0, i);
                    string choose2 = choices.Substring(i + 1);
                    choices = choose1 + choose2;

                    // explore
                    AddTwins(people, choices, chosen + c);

                    // Unchoose
                    string unchoose1 = choices.Substring(0, i);
                    string unchoose2 = choices.Substring(i);
                    choices = unchoose1 + c + unchoose2;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please see http://ericlippert.com/2013/05/14/benchmarking-mistakes-part-one/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You never execute the `LINQ` query, you just create it. You should use `ToList` or `ToArray` method to force an iteration, probably you won't get a different result because `LINQ` uses a `foreach` loop as well.

**Edit**: `LINQ` takes a little bit more time because you are iterating over all of the items. But in your other two loops you are breaking the loop as soon as you find a match. Try using `FirstOrDefault` instead of `Where` and you should get the same (or similar) result.

```
people.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == name);
```

Comment: My bad I just realized that, see the new results/code.

Answer (score 1):

the linq one is taking no time because the query is never actually *evaluated*.

[Linq is lazy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943859.aspx) for most operations, it won't actually do anything until someone starts enumerating the results.

if you added

```
result.Count(); // add this line, query will be evaluated
linqTime = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
stopwatch.Restart();
```

then i'm pretty sure you'd have a non-zero result for linq.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed, but you guys were too quick for me. See the new results. If the LINQ query is supposed to have a foreach just like the foreach loop, why is it slower?

Comment: if you look at the generated code for it, the foreach is probably pretty "flat", where the generated code *probably* has some extra method calls in it to get in/out of the foreach, and yield return things, and stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

It is apparently significant that Sum has to store a boxed instance of the list enumerator on the heap, and use that heap object to iterate the list.  The inline foreach and the for loop both avoid this; the former because List's public GetEnumerator method returns a value type.  If you store a reference to people in an `IEnumerable<Person>` variable, the foreach loop takes a little longer to get to its result.

Also, linq has to create objects for the where iterator and the delegate passed to it, and it does more null checks so it can throw informative exceptions if any of the arguments is null.  That could account for the rest of the additional time required for the linq code.