# Exists some other advantages using Select instead foreach C#

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose these two codes:

1) using foreach with Add in new list

```
var myList = new List<MyType>();
foreach(var myType in otherEntity.ListOfMyType) {
    myList.Add(new MyType {
        //... copy properties here
    });
}
```

2) using select

```
var myList = otherEntity.ListOfMyType.Select(myType => new MyType {
    //... copy properties here
});
```

Exists other advantages on use select instead foreach beyond readability?

Comment: In your case there is little difference between the two pieces of code. There may be some very minor performance differences (minor enough that I doubt you'd notice). So yeah, its just down to readability here I think.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322586/c-sharp-performance-of-linq-vs-foreach-iterator-block)... and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22851234/linq-vs-foreach-vs-for-performance-test-results)... and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156059/is-a-linq-statement-faster-than-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: `Select` is lazy and returns a more general type (`IEnumerable<T>` instead of `List<T>`) which could be an advantage.

Comment: @Lee: I have to admit given the name of the variable I just assumed there was going to be a ToList() call on the end that got left off. I probably should have checked that though. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The major difference between these two pieces of code is deferred execution:

- In the first case, you have a `List<MyType>` which is fully "materialized" in memory
- In the second case, you have an `IEnumerable<MyType>`, which is not taking any memory

If you decide to enumerate `myList` to the middle, the second solution would construct as many entries as needed, while the first construct creates every `MyType` object ahead of time.

On the other hand, having a list make multiple enumerations potentially more expensive in terms of CPU cycles.